# Python. Работа с текстовыми файлами

Tags: python, файлы

Если я вывожу текст из под интерпретатора, то всё идёт нормально. Если же я запускаю файл с расширением "*py*", то он записывает текст или переменны в файл, но ничего не выводит.

Запускал под "*linux*".

Код:

```
f = open('my_file', 'w')
f.write('Hello, ')
f.write('World!')
f.close()


f = open('my_file','r')
f.read(5)
f.read()
```

Comment: Покажите код, укажите желаемое поведение. Укажите как вы уже пробовали чтобы исправить поведение.

Comment: .... попробую вас понять: вы выводите содержимое файла на стандартный вывод ( в первом случае это консоль интрепретатора), и логично что при запуске .ру  ничего не выводится, потому как некуда... вы ведь не позаботились о прорисовке окна своего приложения внутри которого вы и ожидаете увидеть таковое. ... всё зависит от вашей операционной системы ( не знаю о наличии кроссбраузерной оконной библиотеки, вроде есть mono,  но не уверен)

Comment: CockLobster, `f.read()` ***возвращает*** данные, но не пишет их в консоль. Чтобы передать их в консоль, вам надо будет вызвать что-то вроде `print f.read()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При работе в интерактивной консоли, каждое выражение печатается на экран, используя `sys.displayhook()` функцию (по умолчанию вызывается `repr()` для объекта и сам объект сохраняется в переменной с именем `_`):

```
>>> open('/etc/passwd').read(5)
'root:'
>>> _
'root:'
```

В данном случае `.read(5)` возвращает строку из пяти символов. Сам метод `.read()` ничего не печатает, результат выводит Python REPL (оболочка, принимающая ввод, передающая его интерпретатору Питона и печатающая вычисленный результат).

При обычном исполнении результат просто игнорируется (нет интерактивной оболочки). Если хочется использовать результат позже, то ему нужно дать имя:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = open('/etc/passwd').read(5) # этот код не печатает
print(s + s) # печатает root:root:
```

Можно свою функцию создать:

```
def double_input(addable):
    return addable + addable
```

Если её просто вызвать в коде (сохранить в файл и запустить его), то ничто не печатается:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
double_input(u"ничто не печатается")
```

Чтобы напечатать на экране (в стандартном выводе), нужно явно вызвать `print()` функцию:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print(double_input(u"результат "))
```